# Chrome page refresh problem

Tags: javascript

Pressing enter inside a textbox refreshes the whole page in Google Chrome.
please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing Enter in an *input field* submits a form which, depending on your form's action attribute, may well be submitting the form to the same page (causing it to appear like a refresh).  This is intended behaviour.  If you're talking about a *text-area*, then that's an entirely different matter (and is probably relating to some custom JavaScript event).

If this isn't what you mean, you're going to need to clarify your question.  At the very least, please post the excerpt of HTML that encompasses your <form> tags.

Comment: Pressing enter in a textarea shouldn't submit the form, but create a newline char.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I've clarified.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: +1 for the edits. It isn't clear whether the OP means a text input or area.

Comment: <form id="aspnetForm" action="ApplicationMarketPlace.aspx?id=6fa83b63-274c-4ad4-88de-61ae261a9e28" method="post" name="aspnetForm">

Comment: Thanks for the info, but a little bit more would be helpful (sorry)!  Could you edit your original question with the entirety of the form, any JavaScript affecting the form itself.  That way, we can see what the form does completely (i.e. see if it's a text-area or an input field) and also be able to test it out to see if the problem can be reproduced!  Thanks!

Comment: its not like javascript i have asp.net form inside that i have asp textbox clicking inside the textbox refreshes the whole page this happens only in chrome

Comment: Right, okay - what does the onKeyDown event actually do?  (And, again, is it an input-box [i.e. single-line] or a text-area [i.e. multi-line]).  It would be very helpful if you could give some more complete information, it's very difficult to help solve a puzzle without all of the pieces :)